# Creating a struct as enum class member

Tags: c++, enums

I was working on creating a multilevel enum for a Library.

- *I would like something (not necessarily exactly) like this*:

```
Book::Category::PROGRAMMING::C_PLUS_PLUS
```

where `Book` is a `struct` and `Category` is (currently) an `enum class`.
*Basically, I would like to nest enums*.

I know that I can just do:

```
Book::Category::PROGRAMMING_C_PLUS_PLUS
```

But not only will this create a *long* list of values in `Category`, but will make maintaining it a nightmare (I tried to do this with 30, and it was already a headache).

I want to divide and conquer this problem.

**Edit 1**: The reason I didn't want it to be a `std::string` is that it's value can be *anything and everything*. I wanted to constrain the domain of `Category`.

And no, `PROGRAMMING` is not a major part of my Library. Let me try with classes and inheritance.

Basically, the reason I wanted `enum`s was to have a fixed set of valid constants.

---

References:

- [Can enum class be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057140/can-enum-class-be-nested)
   -> I need to create objects of `Book`, and hence it cannot be a namespace. I couldn't understand the answer that used templates.
- [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum) -> Has no answer to my question.

Comment: By forcing them to be fixed and constant, you're forcing yourself into the "headache" situation no matter what. You're forcing yourself to maintain a constant list of valid enums that *may change* at some point, at which point you will have to update your list of enums and **recompile** your code. A malleable solution here would be to allow them to be strings, and read in a .txt file at startup or something, and have that be your list of acceptable values that you can check against if you need to verify.

Comment: @alteredinstance Another very valid point! I think this should work. The program should have code, not a database. That belongs in a separate dedicated file. Do add to the answer! +1

Comment: Glad I was able to be helpful! Let me know how this works for you, hopefully it's not too much of a detour to implement. I think "The program should have code, not a database" is a great way of understanding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it would be a **bad design**.

One common code smell is using an `enum` for what should clearly be a class - the case here being that you want a `C_PLUS_PLUS` genre to be a derivation of the `PROGRAMMING` category.

However, `enum`s are best used to describe possible *states*, and are incapable of inheritance by *design*, as you noted in one of your references. In my opinion, your best course of action would be to make two separate member variables in `Category` that **can hold values** such as `PROGRAMMING` and `C_PLUS_PLUS`, and do away with their status as `enum`s.

Think: what would best encapsulate an open-ended field such as a book genre/subgenre? Are you planning to program ***every single possibility*** with an `enum`? Or would just using two `string`s, (such as `genre` and `subgenre`) better suit an open-ended field such as that?

Or, perhaps, if you are specifically working with `PROGRAMMING` books as a major piece of your design, turn `PROGRAMMING` into a class, and make `C_PLUS_PLUS` part of an `enum` within *that* class. But don't have them both be `enums` - that's just asking for issues down the road, and doesn't solve your issues with maintenance that you already described.

EDIT: Adding from a comment I made -

By forcing them to be fixed and constant, you're forcing yourself into the "headache" situation no matter what. You're forcing yourself to maintain a constant list of valid enums that may change at some point, at which point you will have to update your list of enums and recompile your code. A malleable solution here would be to allow them to be strings, and read in a .txt file at startup or something, and have that be your list of acceptable values that you can check against if you need to verify.

Comment: See my implementation. :-) Thanks again! Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest the `enum`s, however, you can do something like this:

```
struct Book {
    struct Category {
        enum class PROGRAMMING {
            // ...
        };
        enum class COOKING {
            // ...
        }; 
    };
};
```

Similar to using a namespace like in the linked question, but since it is inside a class and you can't do that, you can just use another struct.

Comment: Okayyy. This seems neat. So, basically make all n-1 levels a `struct` and the last level, a real `enum class`. Will still have to be careful to manage it properly.

Comment: If you can't use namespaces for the upper levels, then yes.

Comment: Okay, quick question. What if I have to store a category, that could be `PROGRAMMING` related, or `COOKING` related?

Comment: Then you'd have a problem ;) You can put the same name in each `enum`, but they would be completely separate...

Answer (score 1):

On the request of an answerer, I am posting my implementation for future reference.
This is the `Book`:

```cpp
struct Book
{
    // A Map of categories and its list of sub-categories
    static std::map< std::string, std::vector< std::string > > Categories;

    // default parameter for unit testing, 
    // thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297782/c-unit-testing-check-output-is-correct/59374648#59374648
    static void initBookCategories(std::string file_name = "categories.txt")
    {
        // Open the file in read mode
        std::ifstream allowed_categories(file_name);

        // Check if file open is unsuccessful
        if(!allowed_categories)
        {
            // Signal error and exit
            std::cerr << "\n\nFile Not Found!\nError Initialising DB! Exiting...";
            return;
        }

        // Read the category_name
        std::string category_name;
        // Until there are categories left
        while(std::getline(allowed_categories, category_name))
        {
            // Read the whole sub-category list
            std::string subcategory_names;
            // Untill end of line
            std::getline(allowed_categories, subcategory_names);
            // Convert to std::stringstream for parsing
            std::istringstream parse_subcategories(subcategory_names);
            // Skip the empty line
            allowed_categories.ignore();

            // Now read the sub-categories
            // Need a std::vector to store the list of subcategory names
            std::vector< std::string > subcategory_list;
            // Reusing subcategory_names for each subcategory_name
            while(parse_subcategories >> subcategory_names)
            {
                // Add to the list of sub-categories
                subcategory_list.push_back(subcategory_names);
            }

            // Add this newly read category with its list of subcategories our map
            Categories.insert(std::pair< std::string, std::vector< std::string > >(category_name, subcategory_list));
        }
    }
    static void getCategoryList()
    {
        // For each category
        for(std::pair< const std::string, std::vector< std::string > >& category : Categories)
        {
            // List the sub-categories
            int index = 0;
            // Print the category name
            std::cout << " " << category.first << ":\n";
            // Loop over the sub-categories
            for(std::string& subcategory_name : category.second)
            {
                // Printing each sub-category in a line
                std::cout << "   " << ++index << ") " << subcategory_name << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
};
std::map< std::string, std::vector< std::string > > Book::Categories;
```

And our main function using this:

```
int main()
{
    Book::initBookCategories();
    Book::getCategoryList();
    return 0;
}
```

Last, but not least, the format of `categories.txt`:

```
PROGRAMMING
C_PLUS_PLUS C PYTHON JAVA SQL

MATHEMATICS
CALCULUS ALGEBRA DISCRETE

BIOLOGY
ZOOLOGY BOTANY MICROBIOLOGY BIOTECHNOLOGY

CHEMISTRY
ORGANIC INORGANIC PHYSICAL

SOCIAL_STUDIES
POLITICAL_SCIENCE GEOGRAPHY HISTORY CIVIL_SCIENCE

BUSINESS_ADMINISTRATION
ACCOUNTS MANAGEMENT STATISTICS ECONOMICS

SCIENCE_FICTION
SPACE ALIENS FUTURE WAR ADVENTURE

LITERATURE
ENGLISH HINDI COMEDY NOVEL

PHYSICS
MECHANICS FLUIDS NUCLEAR THERMODYNAMICS

ARTS_AND_HUMANITIES
PHILOSOPHY SOCIOLOGY PSYCHOLOGY ANTHROPOLOGY
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks great! Intuitive and easily extensible on the fly - nice solution :)